# Cross-compiling source code for MIPS32 target

Tags: gcc, mips, cross-compiling, mips32, ecos

I have source code pack which includes eCos source, GSS-3.2.1 compiler and and GCC-toolchain. I want to compile source code for MIPS32 target CPU. The host PC is Ubuntu Linux x86/64. The 'Readme' file have short instructions for building GCC 3.2.1 and eCos library.
As was specified there, in order to compile eCos, I will need to download GCC version 3.2.1 (GCC 3.2.1). In addition, there are note: "The build instructions given here are for the default GCC target platform CPU(i686-linux). This means that the library files created here can not be loaded onto a BRCM MIPS CPU."
Whereas, I want to create files specifically for Broadcom MIPS32 CPU. (BCM33xx)
So, its not clear, how to compile source code for embedded MIPS32 CPU on Linux x86/64 host PC?

Edit: Source package includes also gcc cross-compiler toolchain (gcc-toolchain.tar), containing folder tree:

```
/usr/local/ecos20/gnutools/mipsisa32-elf-i386-linux/
```

Then it's not clear does anything else is needed to compile code and all library files for MIPS32?

Comment: Can you ask Broadcom or whomever for the cross compiler already built?  Otherwise, it's fun time trying to either build your own compiler or finding one.  Some say successfully building your first cross compiler is a rite of passage.  I say, do whatever you can to get whomever to get it for you and not burn the time.

Comment: edit: the package contains also gcc cross-compiler toolchain (gcc-toolchain.tar) containing folders tree: `/usr/local/ecos20/gnutools/mipsisa32-elf-i386-linux/`. How it can be used, with regard to the Readme note, that "the library files created here can not be loaded onto a BRCM MIPS CPU." ?

Comment: Honestly unsure.  I'd be asking local team members if possible about this as that note is strange.